# Do you NEED a library to communicate with Rails using Objective -c?

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm looking through tutorials on creating iOS apps using Rails as a backend, and they all seem to involve a library such as AFNetworking. I can't seem to wrap my head around why it can't just use the JSON (i.e. `"http://localhost:3000/posts.json"`) without involving these libraries.

These tutorials I'm referring to aren't really new and it's possible they're pretty much outdated. After reading about NSURL & before diving into my app, I'm just curious as to why *it may be less feasible* to not use these libraries when it comes to C.R.U.D. (create/read/update/destroy) applications

(I'm using Rails 4 btw, so maybe they introduced something new that would make these libraries unnecessary)

Also, any useful links pertaining to the subject would be much appreciated

Comment: Of course you can do it without a library. But then you'll end up writing (boring) code that has already been written by other people (and extensively tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes understanding the need for something involves working through the evolution of how those libraries came to being.

There is nothing stopping you from directly using NSUrlConnection (or other) and interfacing directly with your web services. It is just HTTP and JSON after all.

However, after it's all said and done you'll probably notice you've written a lot of cruft. Had to handle some interesting corner cases, and ultimately distracted yourself from writing your app.

This is when those libraries come in handy.